# glassfish 4.0 asadmin create-domain error

Tags: netbeans, java-7, glassfish-4, asadmin

I have installed Netbeans 7.3.1 with Glassfish 4.0 on a Fedora 19.
When I try to create a new domain with asadmin as root user:

```
asadmin> create-domain --adminport 5007 domain2
```

I have the following error

```
Enter admin user name [Enter to accept default "admin" / no password]>

You do not have permission to use port 5007 for domain2. Try a different port number or login to a more privileged account.
CLI130: Could not create domain, domain2
Command create-domain failed.
```

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Solved setting the hostname to "localhost" using the command

`sudo hostname localhost`

Answer (score 0):

If you have the permission and the port is not blocked, check your /etc/hosts file. I think you met this problem:

https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-8489